# How to remove extra white space in jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables and having an issue with it

[image]

In **Dest Port** column there is a lot of extra space and same as in **Sub Client** and **Prod Type** columns and my initialization code is:

```
function calcDataTableHeight() {
    return $(document).height() - 320;
}

var browserScrollPercentage = function () {
     if($.browser.chrome) {
        return '178%';
     }else{
        return '228%';
     }
}

var oTable = new Datatable();
oTable.init({
    src: $("#tableOrder"),
    onSuccess: function (oTable) {
        // execute some code
    },
    onError: function (oTable) {
        // execute some code
    },
    loadingMessage: 'Loading...',
    dataTable: {
        "bStateSave": false,
        "bScrollAutoCss": true,
        "lengthMenu": [
            [30, 60, 90, 120, -1],
            [30, 60, 90, 120, "All"]
        ],
        "aoColumnDefs": [ { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 31 ]}],
        "pageLength": 30,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "order-ajax" // ajax source
        },
        "order": [
            [1, "desc"]
        ], // set first column as a default sort by desc
        scrollY: calcDataTableHeight(),
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "sScrollXInner": browserScrollPercentage(),
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "sDom": '<"top">rt<"bottom"pi><"clear">',
        "bInfo": true
    }
});
```

I've tried many things from different sources but didn't succeed I also try trim in my jQuery code and also in PHP code but didn't work for me.

Comment: No no, remove the extra spaces in columns...

Comment: Set the column width?

Comment: Yes I tried but not working properly...

Comment: What is the actual problem? spaces after the text or column width too large? If you've trimmed the whitespace then I suspect the latter, but you haven't shown us what you've tried.

Comment: You can see the Dest Port column so there is record in Busan/South Korea after this there is a lot of space I just want to remove the space after my records in Dest Port column...

Comment: `<th style="width:50px">Sub Client</th>`

Comment: how to adjust automatically column depend on data...

Comment: DataTables automatically sets the column width based on the longest item in the column unless you set the column width manually. You don't have anything in your code that sets the column width manually from what I can see. Are there spaces after the text that are causing this?

Comment: Yes these spaces are after the data/record and I want to remove it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **CAUSE**

Like HTML tables, DataTables attempts to layout tables in an optimal format based on the data in the cells. When content is not long enough to fill the page, there will be white space in some columns.

> **SOLUTION**

You can use [`columnDefs.width`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width) to target specific columns with `targets` and force certain width with `width` option.

For example, to set width of fifth and sixth columns, use the code below:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   columnDefs: [
       { targets: [4,5], width: '10%' }
   ]
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ntLvv9a2/) for code and demonstration.